# Vue.js refresh page when tapping a button

Tags: html, vue.js, button, onclick, page-refresh

I want to refresh the page when I tap the button
This is how the button looks in html `<button v-on:click="getUser()" :class='gender'>Get Random User</button>`

js code under

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Doe',
            email: 'John@Doe.com',
            gender: 'male',
            picture: 'https://picsum.photos/200',
            profile: 'Profile',
        }
    },
    methods: { 
    async getUser() {
            
        $forceUpdate();
            
    }
}
})
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: where do you want to refresh your page ?

Comment: `async getUser() {
            
        $forceUpdate();
            
    }`

Comment: why do you want to refresh your page? I asked this question, maybe you are looking another something.

Comment: I tap the button, then it goes to `getUser() {}`

Comment: okey I understood. but why do you want to refresh your page without reload ?

Comment: @SefaUn It's so the random image changes.

Comment: My understanding, you have a component. And images changing there. but your images can not change ? isn't it?

Comment: I use the random image API

Comment: Okey. you need to use `watch: {}` in vue.js. you can look at that from here. `https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property`

Comment: You need to trigger your variable with `watch`

Answer (score 0):

```
 methods: {
    getUser() {
        window.location.reload()
    }
  }
```